# TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, solver

I know there are plenty of subject on this error and I've been on many of them trying to understand what is going on with sush a simple system. Here is my code, solving a very simple equation to test the efficiency of solve_ivp vs odeint.

```
import numpy as np 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def fun(t,x,a) : 
    return -x/a


t = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
tspan = [t[0], t[-1]]


x0 = [10]

sol = solve_ivp(fun, tspan, x0, t_eval = t, args = 1)

plt.plot(t,sol.y.T)
plt.show()
```

And this is the full error report :

```
/home/anthony/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/common.py:40:         
/home/anthony/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/common.py:40:     
UserWarning: The following arguments have no effect for a chosen solver: `args`.
warn("The following arguments have no effect for a chosen solver: {}."
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
sol = solve_ivp(fun, tspan, x0, t_eval = t, args = 1)
File "/home/anthony/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py", line 
477, in solve_ivp
solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
File "/home/anthony/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py", line 
100, in __init__
self.f = self.fun(self.t, self.y)
File "/home/anthony/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py", line 
139, in fun
return self.fun_single(t, y)
File "/home/anthony/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py", line 
21, in fun_wrapped
return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)
TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

To me, the error is pretty clear but it is also very obvious that I put in the right place my argument according to the documentation of this solver [doc scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)
I also upgraded to the latest my scipy version, any advices would be very helful.

Comment: `args` is supposed to be a tuple.

Comment: Check the scipy version: `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  You need version 1.4.

Comment: I've checked via your method the version of scipy and you're right, I'm running with the 1.3.3 version. I'm confused because I've upgrade via pip install (pip, pip3 and pip3.8 to be sure) with the command `pip install scipy --upgrade` and it gives me this output : `Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scipy) (1.18.3)`

Comment: If I understand right, the package I upgraded is not the same as the one used by VS code in my case. The output of `inspect.getfile(scipy)` is `/home/anthony/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py` whereas the file that I upgraded is in a different file (see previous comment)

Comment: What I did is to copy the latest scipy version inside the directory used by BS code. Thx for yor advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is supposed to be a tuple

```
In [281]: sol = solve_ivp(fun, tspan, x0, t_eval = t, args = (1,))                                     
In [282]: sol                                                                                          
Out[282]: 
  message: 'The solver successfully reached the end of the integration interval.'
     nfev: 80
     njev: 0
      nlu: 0
      sol: None
   status: 0
  success: True
   ....
```

Messing up the `args` is one of the most common `scipy.integrate` (and `optimize`) SO errors.